# What happens when I install a Visual Studio Code extension in the Remote Extension Host

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

What happens (and changes) on the server when I install the Visual Studio Code [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension **in the Remote Extension Host**? I am connected to the server through SSH.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start a remote session, VSCode installs a "VSCode server" on the Linux machine you're connecting to.  That server can install local extensions just like your local copy of VSCode.

Login to your server and look in the ~/.vscode-server folder.